# $K$-homomorphisms from an étale $K$-algebra to a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am somewhat confused by the proof of Theorem 1.5.4 (p.22) (Grothendieck's version of the main theorem of Galois Theory) in Szamuely's [Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamental-Cambridge-Studies-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521888506). The theorem establishes an (anti)equivalence of categories between the category of finite étale $K$-algebras and the category of finite sets equipped with a continuous left $\operatorname{Gal}(K)$-action, where $\operatorname{Gal}(K) = \operatorname{Gal}(K_s : K)$ is the absolute Galois group of $K$ and $K_s$ is a separable closure of $K$.

A $K$-algebra $A$ is a **finite étale $K$-algebra** if $A\cong\prod_{i=1}^n L_i$ where each $L_i$ is a seperable extension of $K$. The main point in the proof is that there is a bijection between $\operatorname{Hom}_K (A,K_s)$ and $\coprod_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}_K (L_i, K_s)$, where $\operatorname{Hom}_K$ denotes the set of $K$-homomorphisms.

To do this, Szamuely claims that every $K$-homomorphism $\phi: A\rightarrow K_s$ induces an injection $L_i\rightarrow K_s$ for *precisely* one factor $L_i$. I find his argument a bit confusing, but this is how I see things; there are homomorphisms $A\xleftarrow{\alpha} K \xrightarrow{\beta} K_s$ since these are both $K$-algebras, and since $A\cong \prod_{i=1}^n L_i$ where each $L_i : K$ is a separable extension we obtain (by composition with the projections) homomorphisms $\alpha_i : K\rightarrow L_i$ for each $i$. Now $\alpha (K)$ is a subfield of $A$, and we have $\phi\circ\alpha = \beta$ since $\phi$ is a $K$-homomorphism, so $\phi(\alpha (K)) = \beta (K)$. Therefore $\phi$ induces an injection on some subfield of $A$ containing $\alpha (K)$. The problem is, it seems like Szamuely regards each $L_i$ as a subfield of $A$ and can then argue that precisely one $L_i$ contains $\alpha (K)$ to cook up an injection $L_i \rightarrow K_s$, when in fact they aren't even subrings, since they don't contain the identity of $A$ (i.e. he seems to be treating $A$ like a coproduct rather than a product).

So does anyone have a *rigorous* and more detailed explanation of this argument than that which features in the book? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is geometrically obvious:

Translating from algebra to affine $K$-schemes you have to determine the $\operatorname {Spec}(K)$-morphisms $$\operatorname {Spec}(K_s)\to \operatorname {Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^n L_i)=\coprod _{i=1}^n\operatorname {Spec}(L_i) $$  Since $\operatorname {Spec}(K_s)$ is a one-point scheme and the right hand scheme is a discrete $n$-point scheme, you get $$\operatorname {Hom}_{\operatorname {Spec}(K)}\bigg ( \operatorname {Spec}(K_s), \coprod _{i=1}^n\operatorname {Spec}(L_i) \bigg )=\coprod _{i=1}^n\operatorname {Hom}_{\operatorname {Spec}(K)}\bigg (\operatorname {Spec}(K_s), \operatorname {Spec}(L_i) \bigg )$$ (beware that this last equality is clearly **not** obtained by the categorical definition of $\coprod$ but by the scheme-theoretic situation!)
Translating back to algebra yields what you want, namely
$$ \operatorname {Hom}_K ( \prod _{i=1}^n L_i,K_s  )=\coprod _{i=1}^n\operatorname {Hom}_K(L_i,K_s )$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you! This really is the first time something has been made clearer to me by using schemes, so I'm very happy you explained it like this.

Comment: Dear Alex, you are welcome. And I'm very happy about your comment: welcome to the merry Schemes Fan Club !

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Georges's answer - perhaps the following is useful?

In algebraic terms, the underlying point we need is:

If $$A = A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n $$
is a finite product of commutative unitary rings,
then every ideal $I\subset A$ is of the form $I = I_1\times \cdots I_n$ - where the $I_i$ need not be necessarily proper. [Proof:
$$ 1 =  (1,0,\cdots,0 ) + \cdots  + (0,\cdots, 0,1),$$ so  we can express any $I$ as a sum of ideals $p_i(I)$, where $p_i$ are the projection maps; $p_i(I)$ are ideals, because the $p_i$ are onto. On the other hand, going the other way, the direct product $I_1\times \cdots \times I_n$ is an ideal of $A$.]

Then: Suppose $F$ is a field over $K$. Every $K$-algebra morphism $L_i\to F$, gives rise to a $K$-algebra morphism $A \to F$. Conversely, a $K$-algebra morphism $A \to F$ must kill a maximal ideal $\mathcal m_i$ of $A$, and the set of the latter are in bijection with the set of fields $L_i$: $A/\mathcal m_i = L_i$.

Comment: Another nice answer; it's very helpful to have two viewpoints on this statement. Thank you!